# add new html table inside an html table while click on the row image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add new table inside a table while click on the row image using jquery

Table1

```
+-------------------------------+
|id      name     place   view  |
+-------------------------------+
|1      arun      abc     image1|
|2      jinu      def     image2|
+-------------------------------+
```

while click the 'image1' i would like to display new table below that clicked row

desired output

```
+----------------------------------+
|id       name     place     view  |
|----------------------------------|
|1       arun       abc      image1|
|                                  | 
|+--------------------------------+| 
||name    fname   last name   age ||
||--------------------------------||
||arun    arun      babu      10  ||
|+--------------------------------+|
|                                  |
|2       jinu      def      image2 |
+----------------------------------+
```

I tried this but no output

```
function validation_over() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type:'post',                                      
        url: '<?php echo site_url('page_control/main_report'); ?>',  //Posting all data          
        data:{
            //fn:"table"     
            district:$('#cbo_district').val(),   
            rpt_nm:$('#cbo_rpt_typ').val(),
            type:$('#rpt_type').val(),
            frm_date:$('#frm_date').val(),
            to_date:$('#to_date').val(),
        },

        dataType: 'json',                 //Data format      
        success: function(data) {         //Receiving data
            if(data.status=="nodata") {
                alert("No data found");
            }

            var sales_tot=0;
            var movie_tot=0;
            var still_tot=0;
            result="<table border='0' name='main_rpt_tbl1' id='main_rpt_tbl' class='table'>";
            result+="<CAPTION><EM>Report:"+data.rpt_nm+"</EM></CAPTION>";

            if(data.typ=="d") {
                result+="<tr><td rowspan='2' colspan='3' style='color:green;'>District:"+data.rate[0].DistrictName+"&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Date:"+data.frm_dat+"</td></tr><tr></tr>";

            } else {
                result+="<tr><td rowspan='2' colspan='3' style='color:green;'>District:"+data.rate[0].DistrictName+"&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Date:"+data.frm_dat+"-"+data.to_dat+"</td></tr><tr></tr>";
            }

            result+="<tr><th rowspan='2'>Centre Name</th>";

            if(data.rpt_nm=="Sales Information") {
                result+="<th rowspan='2'>Total Sales</th><th rowspan='2'>View</th></tr><tr></tr>";

            } else {
                result+="<th rowspan='2'>Total Visitors</th><th rowspan='2'>View</th></tr><tr></tr>";
            }

            for(var i=0;i<data.rate.length;i++) {
                CentreID=data.rate[i].CentreID;
                CentreName=data.rate[i].CentreName;
                adult_tot=data.rate[i].adult_tot;
                child_tot=data.rate[i].child_tot;
                foreign_tot=data.rate[i].foreign_tot;

                if(data.rpt_nm=="Sales Information") {
                    movie_tot=data.rate[i].movie_tot;
                    still_tot=data.rate[i].still_tot;
                }

                tot=parseInt(adult_tot)+parseInt(child_tot)+parseInt(foreign_tot)+parseInt(movie_tot)+parseInt(still_tot);
                //result+="<tr onClick=update(this);centre("+ DistrictCd + ",'tbl')>";
                result+="<tr>";

                result+="<td>"+CentreName+"</td>";
                result+="<td>"+tot+"</td>";

                result+="<td onClick='onClick=get_data("+CentreID+");' id='q'><img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>styles/images/delete.png' title='Delete' width='20' height='20'></td>";
                result+="<td style='display:none'>"+CentreID+"</td>";

                result+="</tr>";
            }   

            result+="</table>";
            $('#main_rpt_tbl').html(result);
        }
    });
}

function get_data(id) {
    var tRow = "<tr><table><tr><td>...</td>...</tr>...</table></tr>";//code for your table
    $(this).parent('tr').after(tRow );
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Comment: insert an iframe inside

Answer (score 1):

say the class of the image is "image"
and you are going to add a row after the cuttent row.

```
var tRow = "<tr><table><tr><td>...</td>...</tr>...</table></tr>";//code for your table

$('.image').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent('tr').after(tRow );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will help you

HTML

```
<table id='mytable'><tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>place</td><td>view</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>A</td><td>C</td><td id='td'>IMG</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>B</td><td>D</td><td id='td'>IMG</td></tr></table>
```

Js

```
var tRow="<tr><td colspan='4'><table id='mytable'><tr><td>id</td><td>name    </td><td>name</td><td>age</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>ABC</td><td>CDE</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>CBD</td><td>ADS</td><td>20</td><td>IMG</td></tr></table></td></tr>";

$('#td').click(function(){ 
$(this).parent('tr').after(tRow );
});
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/xdDHJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

HTML

```
<table>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Place</th>
<th>Image</th>
<tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class='image'>test</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class='image'>test</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class='image'>test</td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".image").click(function(){

        $(this).parent('tr').after("<tr><table><th>name<th/><th>fname<th/><th>lname<th/><th>age<th/><tr><td>abc</td><td>pqr</td><td></td>retest<td>23</td></tr></table></tr>");
    });

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JJLVC/2/)